# Копирование TCHAR* строки из другого потока

Tags: c, многопоточность, кодировка, printf

Я хочу скопировать имя клиента из другого потока. При отладке вижу что передается в поток "клиент1", однако вывести с помощью _tprintf() не получается. В потоке, из которого происходит копирование, "клиент1" выводится правильно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код потока, который пытается скопировать имя:

```
static DWORD WINAPI StdinInfo(LPVOID param)
{
   struct msg msg;
   TCHAR buf[1280] = { 0 };
   parameters* p = (parameters*)param;

  while (TRUE)
  {

   _fgetts(buf, 1280, stdin);
   while (_tcslen(buf) > 0 && buf[_tcslen(buf) - 1] == TEXT('\n'))
        buf[_tcslen(buf) - 1] = TEXT('\0');

   buf[128] = TEXT('\0');
   if (!_tcscmp(buf, TEXT("stop")))
   {
        //printf("Terminating...\n");
        msg.isEmpty = 0;
        msg.type = STOP;
        _tcscpy(msg.message, buf);
        _tcscpy(msg.nickName, p->nickName);

        SendMessage(p, &msg);
        break;
   }
   else if (!_tcscmp(buf, TEXT("exit")))
   {
        msg.isEmpty = 0;
        msg.type = DISCONNECT;
        _tcscpy(msg.message, buf);
        _tcscpy(msg.nickName, p->nickName);
        SendMessage(p, &msg);
        break;
   }

   msg.isEmpty = 0;
   msg.type = MESSAGE;
   _tcscpy(msg.message, buf);
   _tcscpy(msg.nickName, p->nickName);

   _tprintf(TEXT(" IN TREAD %s %s\n"), msg.message, p->nickName);

   SendMessage(p, &msg);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Так же заметил, что если использовать _tcprintf(), то "клиент1" выведется правильно, однако уже не выведется "текст". Пожалуйста объясните почему так происходит, и как решить проблему

Comment: Как вариант - можете использовать [pipes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365780) или другие методы синхронизации данных между потоками.

Answer (score 1):

SendMessage - это быстрая операция, ее нужно трактовать как "положи в очередь вот эту команду и побежали дальше, дожидаться ее завершения не нужно". Так как потоки работают в паралель, то вполне возможно, что когда второй поток решит выполнить обработку строки, в посылающей функции уже могло пройти несколько итераций и содержимое буфера десять раз поменяться. А Вы же передаете не буфер, а просто указатель на него.

Это была причина. Но что же делать? Есть два основных выхода.

1. делать копию буфера перед отправкой ( а можно и полную копию переменных). Но только выделять нужно их динамически, через malloc и подобное. Недостаток этого способа - нужно аккуратно подчищать память после обработки. Так как структура половины структур мне не понятна, код написать не смогу.
2. делать блокировку. Использовать PostMessage. Изменений в коде будет минимум, но и плата за это соответствующая. Теперь вызывающий поток будет блокироваться на время обработки события.

Comment: Простите, не написал, что SendMessage в данном случае мой. Использую я разделяемую память.